# WF 4.5 Breakpoints and Visual Tracking issue

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I am using the code from Kushal's blog:                                  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kushals/archive/2009/12/29/visualworkflowtrackingwithstepservice.aspx

It works as expected when i load a workflow, set some breakpoints and hit run.
Visual feedback works fine too.

The problems show up when i add a new activity to the designer. For example, i've added a new WriteLine. Plain and simple.

[image]

I am not sure why this happens, why do i get those inconsistent data? My breakpoint is drawn, but never hit. Is there a way to refresh somehow the designer without reloading it?

```
            SourceLocationProvider.CollectMapping(documentRootElement, documentRootElement, designerSourceLocationMapping,
               this.wd.Context.Items.GetValue<WorkflowFileItem>().LoadedFile);
```

The designerSourceLocationMapping is populated as above.
I am not sure what details should i mention, the full code example can be found at the link provided - on Kushal's blog. Has anyone encountered this scenario until now and found a solution?

Comment: I cannot seem to see the error - the image is compressed. Can you add a comment including the error and I may be able to assist.

Comment: @DotNetHitMan, in fact, as i see the error is that my recent added activity take some garbage properties. You may see the path there has the "UNRESOLVED: " in front of the real path and StartColumn, StartLine, EndColumn, EndLine are all inconsistent. If you have a couple of minutes, just download the example from Kushal's blog, duplicate one of the activities, put a debug sign on it with F9 and try to debug. I am not sure how should i describe this entirely, there is a lot of code in that example.